# Visual Studio Azure Cloud Service project gives runtime error

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I created a new Azure Cloud service project `'AzureCloudService1'` and added an MVC webrole `'WebRole1'` to it. I changed the configuration of `'WebRole1'` to run for `x64` instead of `AnyCPU` for both Debug and Release. Due to some reason, Visual Studio didn't allow me to change the configuration of `'AzureCloudService1'` to `x64`. Therefore, it continues to be at `AnyCPU`. I had to do this configuration change because a nuget package that I want to install, needs `x64` config.

Then, I installed the nuget package. The nuget package has `Microsoft.Cis.Monitoring.Query.dll`  as one of its DLLs. There are many other DLLs in the package. Upon running the solution in browser, it threw a runtime error. The error as displayed on the browser is given below. If I change the `Copy Local` property of `Microsoft.Cis.Monitoring.Query.dll` in the References section of my solution to `false`, this error goes away and the project runs fine. Can anyone tell me, what is the issue here?

RUNTIME ERROR AS DISPLAYED IN BROWSER :-

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Cis.Monitoring.Query' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Cis.Monitoring.Query' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Source Error: 


 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.Cis.Monitoring.Query' could not be loaded.



=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Cis.Monitoring.Query
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: Microsoft.Cis.Monitoring.Query | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///c:/users/avinash/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/AzureCloudService1/WebRole1/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = c:\users\avinash\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AzureCloudService1\WebRole1\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: c:\users\avinash\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AzureCloudService1\WebRole1\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\avinash\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/51e5fcdf/580d0562/Microsoft.Cis.Monitoring.Query.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/51e5fcdf/580d0562/Microsoft.Cis.Monitoring.Query/Microsoft.Cis.Monitoring.Query.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/users/avinash/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/AzureCloudService1/WebRole1/bin/Microsoft.Cis.Monitoring.Query.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.



Stack Trace: 



[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Cis.Monitoring.Query' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +36
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +21
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Cis.Monitoring.Query' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +738
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +217
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +92
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +290
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +531

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Cis.Monitoring.Query' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9946024
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +90
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261
```

Comment: try to compile for x64. Right click on the project --> Build --> Target Platform to x64